# Bold text does not work with Axlsx ruby gem

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet, styling, axlsx

This style only aligns left, the font is not bold.

```
    bold_italic = styles.add_style :b => true, :i => true 
    bold        = styles.add_style :b => true
    yellow_bg   = styles.add_style :b => true, :bg_color => 'FFF60B',

    sheet.add_row ['År:', Time.now.year, "Pågår"],  
      :style => [bold_italic, yellow_bg, bold]
```

The yellow_bg styling also works. Is there a new syntax for getting the font bold?

Comment: What program are you using to read the spreadsheet?  Using the `:b=>true` param works for me when reading spreadsheets with Excel.  Also, what is the `bold` style that you are passing to the `add_row` method?

Answer (score 6):

:b => true does not work in Numbers. Only in Excel.

Thanks for the help, guys! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see `bold` defined as a style. Have you tried `bold = styles.add_style :b => true`?

What is happening underneath is you are adding a set of cells(`values`) and it is mapping them to `styles` by index unless you pass a single style then this will apply to all `values`. So you are stating the following

for  `'År:'` use `bold_italic`,

for `Time.now.year` use `yellow_bg`,

for `"Pågår"` use `bold`

but since `bold` is not a style i.e. `nil` it does not assign a style.

From `Axlsx::Cell#initialize`

```
self.style = val unless val.nil? || val == 0
```

Comment: I forgot to copy the declaration of the bold variable when I posted here. Sorry about that. :-)